# How do I program a pendulum effect in Python?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on making a game in Python (teaching myself Python in the process) and I'm trying to add a pendulum function, but I've never programmed a pendulum function before or even seen code that successfully creates a pendulum. So I'm hoping you guys can help me out here. How exactly do I create a pendulum function in Python?

Comment: Can you describe what you want a little more precisely? Do you just want something that will swing back and forth regularly, or do you want it to interact with other objects?

Comment: What I want is a pendulum with friction that's influenced by a player's momentum and gravity.

Comment: It depends a bit on how close to physical reality it should be, for example if the pendulum can overturn or stays in the lower angles around its lower stable point. Maybe reading something like http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/Pendulum.html may help you a bit.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you need an algorithm (since you say that you want to create a pendulum function). After searching a little bit, i found something that may work for you :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def pendulum(T, n, theta0, v0, alpha):
    """Return the motion (theta, v, t) of a pendulum."""
    dt = T/float(n)
    t = linspace(0, T, n+1)
    v = zeros(n+1)
    theta = zeros(n+1)
    v[0] = v0
    theta[0] = theta0
    for k in range(n):
        theta[k+1] = theta[k] + dt*v[k]
        v[k+1] = v[k] - alpha*dt*sin(theta[k+1])
    return theta, v, t

from scitools.std import *
try:
    n = int(sys.argv[1])
    T = eval(sys.argv[2])
    v0 = eval(sys.argv[3])
    theta0 = eval(sys.argv[4])
    alpha = eval(sys.argv[5])
except:
    print "usage:", sys.argv[0], "n T v0 theta0 alpha"
    sys.exit(1)

theta, v, t = pendulum(T, n, theta0, v0)
plot(t, v, xlabel='t', ylabel='velocity')
figure()
plot(t, theta, xlabel='t', ylabel='velocity')
```

source : [vefur.simula.no/intro-programming/src/ode/pendulum.py](http://vefur.simula.no/intro-programming/src/ode/pendulum.py)